# TClientDataSet error "Trying to modify read-only field"

Tags: delphi, ado, tclientdataset, tdatasetprovider

I use the next chain

```
TADOQuerry->TDataSetProvider->TClientDataSet
```

to got data for Items and ItemType table and work with it offline.
Item TADOQuery's SQL property contains a simple query

```
select i.ID,i.Name, i.TypeID, i.Qnty, i.Price, it.TypeName 
from Items i join ItemType it on (it.ID = i.TypeID)
```

ItemType's even simpler:

```
select * from ItemType
```

now - for cdsItems I modify TypeName field to be an look-up field and chain it to cdsItemType - nothing uncommon - and bound cdsItems to a grid.
But when I try to modify data through using combobox in grid - it throws an error  "Trying to modify read-only field".

I set to all fields of both TCliendDataSet ReanOnly:= false.
Also, after I got data into TClientDataSets - using an for - I set again to all fields ReadOnly:=False.
But even that I still got "Trying to modify read-only field".

Used database is MS SQL Server 2005 Express edition.

Comment: Have you tried setting read-only to false on the fields of the ADOQuery?

Comment: already - in both design and run time

Comment: When you changed the TypeName field in cdsItems into a lookup field, did you also change the query not to include the TypeName field anymore?

Comment: no, should I exclude it?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you get two interfering field descriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FOUND!!!!**

The bug where located in the type of TypeID column of GetItems query (ADOQuery type) - when I loaded all the field into it - the TypeID where added as TAutoIncField - when I changed it to TIntegerField - everything goes well.

Comment: Awesome answer. To fix my problem, I edited both the .pas and the .dfm to redefine the TField definition as TIntegerField instead of TAutoIncField so that Delphi would allow me to assign values to the TClientDataSet field. I mean, why should I not be able to do that if I want to!?